# Help in probabilistic proof of the Caro-Wei theorem

Tags: graph-theory, probabilistic-method

While studying Turan's theorem, I would like to ask about some parts of this proof. I am weak at probability, so unless I spread and open everything up and formalize, I would not be able to understand. I have checked some posts in MSE too but either they asked different things or I just could not understand them.

I want to know why every graph $G$ of $n$ vertices has a clique of size $\geq \sum_{v\in V(G)}\frac{1}{n-d(v)}$. So, here is my understanding so far:

In a few notes I have checked, they start by considering a random permutation $p$ on $V=V(G)$, and consider the set $Q_p$, which is the set of vertices adjacent to all vertices on their left in $p$. I can see why this is a clique. Next, consider the random variable $X=|Q_p|$. Here is my confusion: (Question 1) Does this mean the sample space is $S=\{Q_p\mid p \text{ is an permutation of }V\}$, or just $S=\{p\mid p \text{ is a permutation of }V\}$?

From that definition of $X$, I really thought it can only mean the first sample space, but now I am guessing that it is actually the second one. That means the random variable $X$ assigns any $p$ to $|Q_p|$, am I right?

And so, if $v$ is any vertex, consider the random variable $X_v$, defined such that $X_v(p)=1$ if $v\in Q_p$ and $0$ otherwise. Then, $X=\sum_{v\in V(G)}X_v$. (Question 2: If I use the first $S$ instead and then define $X_v(Q_p)$ in the same way, then this summation still holds (whether it is useful or not), right?).

From here, I simply need to use linearity of expectation, but I need the quantity $E[X_v]=P(X_v=1)$. To get this, I try to count everything, which is

$$P(X_v=1)=P(\{p\mid X_v(p)=1\})=\frac{|\{p\mid X_v(p)=1\}|}{n!}.$$

The numerator is the same as the number of $p$ such that $v\in Q_p$, or eqv such that $v$ appears before any of its non-neighbours (there are $n-d(v)-1$ of them without $v$ itself). To count this, we first put $v$ and all non-neighbors of $v$ in the $n$ boxes (done in $\binom{n}{n-d(v)}$ ways), permute them except $v$ since it has to appear first (done in $(n-d(v)-1)!$ ways), and permute the rest in $d(v)!$ ways. Thus,

$$P(X_v=1)=\frac{\binom{n}{n-d(v)}(n-d(v)-1)!d(v)!}{n!}=\frac{\frac{1}{(n-d(v))!}(n-d(v)-1)!}{1}=\frac{1}{n-d(v)}.$$

And we are done. Is this a correct understanding? If I use the first sample space instead, can this result be obtained too? I am having trouble counting $Q_p$ if I use the first $S$.

Lastly, without counting everything, is there any other way to get the $\frac{1}{n-d(v)}$ quicker?
Thank you.

EDIT: The rest follows from first moment method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct sample space is in fact the set of all permutations of $V$. That's why the solution begins "consider a random permutation of $V$". If the solution were written a bit more carefully, it would begin "consider a uniformly random permutation of $V$", which tells you that you are sampling uniformly from the set of all permutations.

Using a random $Q_p$ gets you into trouble. If your sample space is "subsets $Q_p$ of $V$", then you're not sampling uniformly. So how are you sampling? You don't know. Then you can't compute any probabilities.

As for the quick way to see that $\Pr[X_v = 1] = \frac1{n - d(v)}$, let $S \subseteq V$ consist of $v$, together with all vertices *not* adjacent to $v$. We have $X_v = 1$ if $v$ is the leftmost vertex of $S$ in the permutation (no matter where vertices of $V-S$ go).

A uniformly random permutation of $V$ induces a uniformly random permutation of $S$. The probability that $v$ is the first vertex in this uniformly random permutation of $S$ is $\frac1{|S|}$, by symmetry: any of the $|S|$ vertices in $S$ is equally likely to be first. So $\Pr[X_v = 1] = \frac1{|S|} = \frac1{n-d(v)}$.

Comment: I see. I still have questions about your last paragraph. I have seen it somewhere too, where we consider the set $S$ you define, but I still cannot get why this statement holds: $P(X_v=1)=\frac{1}{|S|}$. Correct me as here I am writing the details: Are we looking at a second sample space $\{\text{permutations of } S\}$? We define a r.v. $Y$ on this as $Y(p)=1$ if $v$ is the first in $p$, right? Hence, $P(Y=1)=\frac{1}{|S|}$. However, I am not sure how to formally see $P(X_v = 1) = P(Y = 1)$, or whether this is the correct writing. Thanks.

Comment: I should have said also in my comment above that my definition $X_v$ is still not updated, as opposed to yours in your third paragraph. I guess that is part of/similar to my comment question too, as in why we safely update $X_v$.

Comment: I'm not sure why you mean by "updated". I think the answer to your question is that if $p$ is a uniformly random permutation of $V$, then $p$ restricted to $S$ is a uniformly random permutation of $S$; you can express this via a sample space, or via a permutation-valued random variable "$p$ restricted to $S$"...

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure I understand. By "updated", I mean, my original $X_v$ is defined as a function on the sample space $\Omega=\{\text{permutations of } V\}$, but in my first comment I changed the sample space and defined $Y$ instead, as it is what I understood from your answer. I guess we may forget it, my bad. Now, about $P(X_v=1) = \frac{1}{|S|}$, I understand why $p$ restricted to $S$ is a random permutation of $S$, but the language to obtain $P(X_v=1) = \frac{1}{|S|}$ is what I could not get (as I mentioned I am weak at this language). (to be continued)

Comment: (to continue) When we say "$p$ is a random permutation of $V$", that means there exists a sample space $\Omega = \{\text{permutations of } V\}$ and let $p\in \Omega$, right? But, say I let $q=p \text{ restricted to }S$, when we say "$q$ is a random permutation on $S$", certainly the sample space is no longer $\Omega$, since $q$ is no longer an element in $\Omega$, right? That's why I thought we are using a different sample space now, which is $\{\text{permutations of }S\}$, as it is where $q$ lies. So now we must relate $Pr(v \text{ is first in }q)$ (which is $\frac{1}{|S|}$) (to be continued)

Comment: Think of $q$ as a random variable: it is the obvious function $\{\text{permutations of }V\} \to \{\text{permutations of }S\}$.

Comment: (to continue) and $Pr(X_v = 1)$. I cannot (formally) see why these two are equal.

Comment: OK let me expand. Firstly, what you mean is actually set-valued random variable, right? I read it only a few minutes ago haha. Secondly, finally, let $v,\Omega$ be as above, let $S:=\{v \text{ and all non-neighbours of it}\}$, let $\Sigma:=\{\text{permutations of } $S$\}$, let $q$ be as you said, mapping $\Omega$ to $\Sigma$, and let $Y$ be a random variable on $\Sigma$ such that $Y(\sigma)=1$ if $v$ is first in $\sigma$, and $0$ otherwise. Hence, $X_v = Y \circ q$. Thus, $Pr(p : X_v(p)=1)=Pr(p : (Y \circ q)(p) = 1)=\frac{(S-1)!}{S!} = \frac{1}{S}$. Is this OK?

Comment: Yep, that works. You usually don't need to think about things on that level of formality, but it's good to be able to get there if necessary.

Comment: Actually, I think I made a mistake in the second to last equality. That actually does not hold since the $Pr$ function still is the cardinality of events in $\Omega$ divided by $|\Omega|$, not $\Sigma$. Do you know how to work around this? (to be continued)

Comment: (to continue) Meanwhile, I think I have found another approach: To recover the whole $\Omega$, we take all permutations of $V$ such that $v$ appears before its non-neighbours (done in, say $m$ ways), and permute the $S$-vertices in each of them (there are |S|! ways), but this double-counts the ordering of $|S|-1$ non-neighbours of $v$, so we throw them away. Hence, $|\Omega|=\frac{|S|!m}{(|S|-1)!}$, hence $\frac{m}{|\Omega|}=\frac{1}{|S|}$ as desired. Is this OK?

Comment: Regarding your formality comment, yes. It's just that I have not developed enough intuition in probability. The moment you mentioned "... induces ...", I have no idea what it means, just like in algebra where people write "this homomorphism induces the homomorphism" without specifying what the induced homomorphism is, because it may come in many ways. However, it's algebra and I am quite comfortable already, but not at this probability theory haha. Sorry I have not yet marked your answer, as I really plan to when I understand this whole thing.

Comment: $\Pr[(Y \circ q)(p) = 1] = \Pr[Y(q \circ p) = 1]$ by associativity of composition, and $q \circ p$ restricted to $S$ is a uniformly random permutation of $S$. (There are $(n-|S|)!$ different $p$ that result in the same $q \circ p$.) Your second approach seems correct, too.

Comment: Actually, if I were formalizing the idea, I would want to say that for every element of $S$, the probability that it's the first element of $S$ ought to be the same by symmetry: if $x,y \in S$, the permutations where $x$ comes first are in bijection with the permutations where $y$ comes first, by swapping $x$ and $y$. So the probability is equal for all of them. The probabilities add up to $1$, so each probability must be $\frac1{|S|}$. This avoids any use of factorials.

Comment: By the way I have marked your answer. For your second comment, I think I can see it that way too. For your first comment, this is where I do not get it: Formally, by definition we have $Pr((Y\circ q)(p) = 1) = Pr(\{p\in \Omega \mid (Y\circ q)(p) = 1\})$, correct? In your RHS, I get why it becomes $Pr(Y(q(p))=1)$, but again, this equals $Pr(\{p\in \Omega \mid Y(q(p))=1\})$, right? I mean, by definition, the probability function is defined on $2^\Omega$. (If the sample space is $\Sigma$ instead, then we safely write $Pr(Y(q(p)=1)=Pr(\{q(p)\mid Y(q(p))=1\})$). Hence, my confusion.

Comment: If I look at $Pr(\{p\in \Omega \mid (Y\circ q)(p) = 1\})$, that means I must count $|\{p\in \Omega \mid (Y\circ q)(p) = 1\}|$, which is the number of $p$ such that when restricted to $S$, $v$ comes first. So, there are (as you noted) $(n-|S|)!(|S|-1)!$ such $p$, hence this gives $\frac{(n-|S|)!(|S|-1)!}{n!}$, but still times $\binom{n}{|S|!}$ because of the position, which gives the result. However, this returns to the old way of counting everything tho haha

Comment: You don't need to formally figure out $(n-|S|)!$ as long as you know it's a constant which cancels out, but yes.

Answer (score 1):

I like to think of Caro Wei's theorem just as the expected result of the greedy algorithm to get an independent set.

You start out with an empty set and consider each vertex once in a specific order, if there are no neighbours of the vertex in the set then you insert the vertex, otherwise you don't.

If the order in which you process the vertices is random then vertex $v$ will be inside the set with probability at least $\frac{1}{d(v)+1}$ (because if $v$ is the first element among the $d(v)+1$ vertices consisting of itself and  its $d(v)$ neighbours then $v$ will definitely be inserted). Lineality of expectation yields the desired bound for the expected value of the final set.

This way of looking at it also shows clear avenues which could be followed to improve the results.